# Custom portal: server-side sign-in

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

We have been using APIM since 2018. As the legacy portal has been deprecated and we wanted more freedom, we decided to skip the default APIM portal altogether, and to embed the APIM API methods in our own website, using Postman as the documentation portal.

Most of the methods are straightforward, but it's not clear how to sign-in the user? We can, of course, fetch their statistics and API keys, but how do we know they are who they claim they are?

The code in the self-hosted portal in GitHub is more client-side oriented.

EDIT. From [the usersService.ts module](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/blob/master/src/services/usersService.ts) it appears that GET /identity with the `Authorization` header made of `Basic`  and base64-encoded pair of *userId:password* is to be invoked.

But I keep getting:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationFailedInvalidHeader",
        "message": "Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format."
    }
}
```

Changing `Basic`  to `Bearer`  predictably yields `InvalidAuthenticationToken`.

Comment: @mikebudzynski?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved (with the help of Microsoft support who sent a screenshot of the method being invoked on their side).

It seems that the method is not to be invoked from `management.azure.com` like all the other methods. Nope. It has to be invoked from the *Management API URL* that can be found in the *Management API* section of your APIM in Azure.

Curiously, the management API toggle does not even have to be on.

Your GET request should be like this:

https://**my_apim_instance**.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/**my_subscription_id**/resourceGroups/**my_resource_group**/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/**my_apim_instance**/identity?api-version=2019-12-01

Now cue in the ever-helpful posters with ever-useful post-solution advice.

Comment: GitHub conversation: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/discussions/1327